# What site for general question about handling installation of software on Linux?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I commonly need to install packages on a Linux server behind a firewall.  The Linux repositories are not enabled, and there is no internet connection.  I often go to the Internet, get a file manually, then I try to install it.  I discover that a dependency is not installed or not the right version.  I repeat process to fix the problem.  There is an endless cycle of dependencies.

What is the solution to this problem?  Numerous systems administrators must go through this laborious problem.  If enabling repositories isn't an option, and going directly to the Internet from the Linux server is not an option, what should a systems administrator do?  I'd like to have a complete list of every dependency (and every dependency thereof) with compatible versions and locations on the Internet where a binary file exists to transfer over and install.  Installing from source is more tedious than installing binaries.

I'd like to ask this on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) but I think the moderators don't like questions like these.  I am reluctant to think the solution would come from [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but that doesn't sound like a bad idea.

Which site is the most appropriate for my question?

Comment: First two paragraphs can be posted in [super user](http://superuser.com/) or '[unit & linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)'& Last paragraph can be posted here in this meta.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), if it's about Linux in general and isn't a good fit for any of the following. If your question is about [Ubuntu Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)), it may be on topic on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). If it's about general userland software mostly nonspecific to Linux in general, it might be a good fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com). If you're looking for a piece of software with a specific purpose and objectively fulfillable requirements, it might be on-topic on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).