# No notification for comment reply when using Dupe Hammer along with other close voters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, comment-replies, dupehammer

User who cast a binding close vote on a question should be notified when someone comment-reply him/her, even without ever leaving a comment.

This still works fine when I am the only close voter, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/private-message-feature) (tried with my sock and deleted the comment already), however this fails to work when I'm not the only close voter, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277278/what-site-for-general-question-about-handling-installation-of-software-on-linux).

Tested both with a sock account and with the help of another user - no notification.

I noticed it yesterday and hoped it was a temp glitch, but then today I saw by chance [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277301/why-there-is-no-direct-interaction-to-other-members-on-a-se-site#comment898330_277301), which is important for me to be notified about, since I can reopen the question with single vote.

Just to prove, a screenshot: (click to enlarge, don't want to clutter)

> [image]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: This behavior [seems to have changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345569/280545).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way this works is, if you're *solely responsible* for an action on a post, you're pingable.

- If you create the post, you're pingable
- If you leave a comment, you're pingable
- If you edit the post, you're pingable
- If you rollback, you're pingable
- If you edit the list of duplicate targets, you're pingable
- **If *you alone* caused the post to be** closed, reopened, deleted, undeleted, protected, unprotected... Then you're pingable.

As soon as someone else participates in one of those actions, it no longer causes you to be eligible for a comment @-reply. If you want to be anyway, then the easiest solution is to leave a comment.

Comment: Or edit the list of duplicates using the hammer, no? (Dummy edit even, e.g. add some random question then remove it right away.)

Comment: Yes, but that's kinda taking the long route... If you want folks to ping you about closing the post, just ask them: "Hey, I think this is a duplicate, but if you disagree lemme know!"

Comment: That's... not a bad idea.

Comment: Your answer contradicts the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/377214), which says that *any* user who bindingly closed should be notified, regardless of whether or not there were others voting to close. Can you please edit?

Comment: ...you just edited something I wrote to change "near" to "as far as", but you're afraid to add a clarification of "binding" to a community-wiki FAQ? Change "binding" to "unilateral" and it will become accurate.

Comment: Can you please explain why the decision was made to make binding voters non-pingable if others also participated in the voting?

Comment: Before my time, but I'll bet it was like 3 people in a room, gathered around a hardwood table dimly lit by a green-shaded lamp, guns drawn in a Mexican standoff... And then a fourth enters the room, the tension practically dripping from the walls, and calmly says, "what if we just took the ID of the user associated with the revision?"

Comment: Perhaps this shouldn't apply when Community has edited the post, too?