# Autocomplete for @ reply to the person who marked a question as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, comment-replies

When commenting on a comment below a question, I can use the `@`, and the first letter of the person I want reply to, and get a little pop-up with their display name in it. If I use that, the person will get notified of my comment.

You can't just type `@` and then the display name of the person, because things like spaces, and who knows what else, should be left out. So the pop-up is quite essential.

I *like* this feature, and it works great, except in the following situation:

If someone marks a question as a duplicate you cannot reply to them in this way, because their display name will not appear in the little pop-up when you type `@` and their first letter.

So that is the feature I would like to see added.

It's a small thing, but I don't understand why I can reply to another comment, but not to someone who marks a question as a duplicate. That person clearly has an opinion about the question.

I do see that I could vote to *reopen* the question. I doubt that's used very often.

Comment: You can actually reply to close voters, *but* they don't show up in the autocomplete; is this a suggestion to be able to reply to them or for them to show up in that autocomplete? (Because the former is already implemented but the latter makes total sense.)

Comment: It is clearly the latter: to let them show up in the autocomplete.

Comment: @Glorfindel That is indeed almost a duplicated, I'll upvote that question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I wasn't sure whether “you cannot reply to them in this way” was meant to say you can't pick their name out or you can't reply to them at all, and the title's talking about being able to @ reply, not just to have them show up in the autocomplete. I suggest it's not all that clear (it's why I asked); you may want to rephrase some parts.

Comment: "I do see that I could vote to reopen the question. I doubt that's used very often." - if you don't use it, it won't get used. Casting a reopen vote will send it to the reopen queue, where people will evaluate it and decide if it should be reopened. It's not only the original close voters who can make a decision about it.

Comment: @doppelgreener not all close voters, only those with binding vote: either dupe gold hammer, or a mod. Pretty sure I tested it before, and "ordinary" close voter can't be pinged, i.e. not getting any notification. Edit: see [this official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310869/152859) for the full details: "If you alone caused the post to be closed, reopened, deleted, undeleted, protected, unprotected... Then you're pingable."