# Is single-vote-to-close too powerful of an ability to hand out?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

An hour after it was posted, my question was instantly closed by somebody with a gold badge as a duplicate of a (vaguely-posed) question whose sole answer cannot be used to solve my Minimal, Reproducible Example.

I had no warning, no chance to explain to the user the differences between my question and the one they claimed it was a duplicate of,     and no chance to edit something in to explain to would-be voters prior to the close.  Now it is almost certainly doomed to fall unnoticed into oblivion without ever being reopened.

Isn't this a little too much power for one person?  It seems to me that, had somebody else voted to close the question *before* the gold badge user arrived, I would have actually had a chance of rescuing it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194479#194479 (and you can both comment and edit while the question is on hold; all that can't happen is adding new answers)

Comment: Speaking for myself, (almost) every time I unilaterally close a question I leave a comment explaining that it seems to be a duplicate of another question, but that the questioner can edit to clarify why it’s not. That usually seems to work.

Comment: See this related question: [Allow gold badge users to "propose" duplicates, to give the author a chance to contest the proposed duplicate](/questions/309993/allow-gold-badge-users-to-propose-duplicates-to-give-the-author-a-chance-to-c)

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Is the dupehammer (Mjölnir) still being evaluated, and if so, what is the current outcome?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298810/839601)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anyone who can close a question with one vote can also re-open it with one vote. Post a comment addressing them by name and explaining why you believe your question is different: (e.g. "Hi, @ExpHP - that other question is about overlaying multiple charts, but mine concerns using both alpha and a colormap to represent different information channels; please take another look when you get a chance...")

Comment: Okay, that softens the blow a bit.  I was not aware of this special case for @-mentions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277312/no-notification-for-comment-reply-when-using-dupe-hammer-along-with-other-close/310869#310869 .  It has such strong limitations though...

Answer (score 9):

Designating a question that appears to be a duplicate as a Duplicate sooner rather than later prevents poor quality (potentially duplicate) answers being provided to a question that is not yet clearly unique and thus ready to be answered.

You now have a chance to explain the differences between your question and the duplicate by editing your question.  Your edit, within 5 days, will place your question into the queue to review whether it is ready for re-opening.