# What actually happens when you edit a closed question?

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

If you post a question which is closed very quickly, perhaps by a moderator rather than community votes, what actually *happens* when you edit it or comment on it in attempt to get it re-opened?

Do the people who have voted to close it, or used their moderator powers, get notified "hey take another look?" What's the mechanics? I don't think *I* have ever seen again a question I voted to close, so if the OP put time into improving it that is wasted on me!

Comment: The question gets put in the [reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) queue

Comment: TL;DR: as @Luuklag said it's being added to a review queue, so surely no time is wasted. While those who closed don't get notification, any user who choose to check the reopen review queue will get to see it and get chance to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @Luuklag not it's not a dupe of that question. That asks _how_ a question get's re-opened, I am asking what happens when I make a change. Your linked Q doesn't appear to mention the re-open queue for example

Comment: The "editing to reopen" section seems to be exactly the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Catija my mistake- thanks

Comment: @Mr.Boy Note that with editing, you only get one chance in getting the question into the reopen review queue. If you make a superficial edit, the question will probably go in and out of the queue without being reopened. Then, if you make a good edit that actually fixes the problems with the question, it will _**not**_ go into the reopen review queue again.

Comment: *"I don't think I have ever seen again a question I voted to close"* - that's totally up to you. There is the *somewhat* new feature of [following posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). I tend to occasionally follow questions I close exactly for the reason to be notified when it's edited and be able to vote to reopen, if worthy

Comment: And if a moderator or gold-badge holder [hammered the question closed alone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310869/1017231), you can ping them in the comments, which is useful after editing to check if you've fixed the issue